# PostgreSQL connection require a valid client certificate

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect via SSL to a PostgreSQL using FireDac in Delphi. I have followed the instructions at the following site:
https://www.howtoforge.com/postgresql-ssl-certificates

I have created all the certificates. Configured the postgreql.conf as specified so it points to the required files. Copied the specified files to the client machine and installed the root.crt certificate.

Via FireDAC's connection params I have specified the following:

```
Params.values[SSL_ca']:=sslCertsPath+'root.crt';
Params.values['SSL_cert']:=sslCertsPath+'postgresql.crt.';
Params.values['SSL_key']:=sslCertsPath+'postgresql.key';
```

I am getting a connection error re invalid client certificate. I am not sure which certificate it is referring to and why it is invalid. Am I specifying the correct client certificates by way of the connection's params? If so, any suggestions as to why I may be getting the error please?

OpenSSL verify against the root.crt and postgresql.crt confirms the certificate is ok.

Answer (score 1):

After over 3 weeks of frustration trying to set up PostgreSQL with SSL using FireDAC, I have finally figured out what the problem is and what the solution is.

For anyone wishing to connect using FireDAC, the howtoforge guide (see link in original post) works fine.

However, do not use the FireDAC parameters in my original post. PostgreSQL does not use them. You need to use the `PGAdvanced` parameter.

But even after figuring this out, I still could not get it to work for weeks until after testing I got an error message which finally made it clear what I was doing wrong. On Windows PostgreSQL strips out path delimiters unless you escape them (this is not mentioned in the PostgreSQL or FireDAC help files as far as I can see).

Below is an example of the correct way to connect using FireDac paramaters for ssl

```
Params.values['PGAdvanced']:='sslmode=verify-ca sslrootcert=C:\\ProgramData\\MWC\\Viewer\\Certs\\root.crt sslcert=C:\\ProgramData\\MWC\\Viewer\\Certs\\postgresql.crt sslkey=C:\\ProgramData\\MWC\\Viewer\\Certs\\postgresql.key';
```

If you don't wish to use a root certificate set `sslmode` to `require`.